# write hash_map as a json file into a zip file in java

Tags: java, serialization, zip

I need to append a hash map as json file into zip file as new zip entry.

I tried the following code:

```
Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
map1.put("a","b");
zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("info.json"));
ByteArrayOutputStream ba = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oba = new ObjectOutputStream(zipOutputStream);
oba.writeObject(map1);
oba.close();
```

but the above code after executing the contents of the json in the zip file is not proper.

Comment: Read the documentation for https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html It has nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: Also `ba` is unused in your code -- what is it for? Look at jackson or gson for serialisation to JSON.

Comment: "but the above code after executing the contents of the json in the zip file is not proper." - Then you have a mistake somewhere. Seriously: you need to provide more details on the error (e.g. error messages, unexpected results etc.) for us to help.

Comment: One thing: how do you expect `oba.writeObject(map1);` to use Json as the serialization format?

Comment: @tgdavies I am the ba object (ByteArrayOutputStream ) to write the contents into the ZipOutPutStream as follows.     
            zipOutputStream.write(ba.toByteArray());
            zipOutputStream.close();
            zipFile.close();

Comment: @Thomas error in the sense  it is not throwing any runtime error , I am able to form the zip , but when I unzip the contents I am not getting the same map contents

Comment: @Thomas here is the example of map and its content the zip  map1.put("akey", "aval"); map1.put("bkey", "bval");         content from zip file  cat info.json 
��srjava.util.HashMap���`�F
loadFactorI     thresholdxp?@
                             takeytavaltbkeytbvalx%

Comment: Just as I said `oba.writeObject(map1);` won't create json. You need a json library to serialize the object into a string and then write that string to the file.

Comment: @Thomas thanks for the info after converting the map into json and then to string to bytes I got the desired output the error for the above code is ObjectOutputStream uses binary format to encode object.